@Transaction in Android Room seems to not working as expected
In below code seems that Flow is emitted between deleteAll and insertAll.. I expected to perform these methods together as a transaction. Am I missing something?
private const val RECENT_UPDATE_THRESHOLD_MS = 60_000L

@Dao
interface InboxMessageDao {
    @Query(
        "SELECT * FROM inbox_message " +
                "WHERE toEmail == (SELECT email FROM email_address WHERE isCurrent = 1) " +
                "AND (strftime('%s', 'now') * 1000 - cacheLastUpdate) < $RECENT_UPDATE_THRESHOLD_MS"
    )
    fun getAllFlow(): Flow<List<InboxMessageEntity>>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertAll(messages: List<InboxMessageEntity>)

    @Query("DELETE FROM inbox_message")
    suspend fun deleteAll()

    @Query("SELECT cacheLastUpdate FROM inbox_message WHERE toEmail == :toEmail LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun getCacheLastUpdate(toEmail: String): Long?

    @Transaction // TODO: This fails tests sometimes, why?
    suspend fun refreshInboxMessages(newMessages: List<InboxMessageEntity>) {
        deleteAll()
        // Flow seems to be propagated here giving me sometimes empty list in androidTests
        insertAll(newMessages)
    }
}

I expect Flow being emitted after whole transaction performed.
PS. runInTransaction {} doesn't fix this problem..
PS 2. Here is my example androiTest:
@Test
fun shouldPropagateOneMessage() = runTest {
        // given
        coEvery { repository.getInboxMessagesFromApi() } returns listOf(inboxMessage)

        val viewModel = InboxMessageViewModel(StandardTestDispatcher(testScheduler))
        advanceUntilIdle()

        // expect
        val result = viewModel.uiState.first()
        advanceUntilIdle()

assertThat(result).isEqualTo(ViewModelState.Success(listOf(inboxMessage)))
}

And the result, ViewModelState.Empty is emitted only in one place, when I get emptylist.
test result

@Transaction is definitely running this as a transaction. Can you show your android test and how you've set that up and what makes you think the empty list is displayed in the middle of the refreshInboxMessages call (how do you even write a test that verifies the state in the middle of that suspending method?).

Hi, I edited my post ^

You've left out a lot of code between your Dao and your test (a repository, a ViewModel) that means your issue is not reproducible with just the code you have listed.
